# Missing peer dependencies

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, npm-install, peer-dependencies

I am new to `npm` and angular projects, and I am using `bootstrap@4.1.1` in my `package.json`. When I do npm install, I get the following error -

```
bootstrap@4.1.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Does this mean that I need to add `jquery@1.9.1 - 3` to my `package.json` under `peerDependencies` section, apart from installing it locally with `no-save` option?

Also, do we need to install this missing peer dependency on the build server as well? Or can it be ignored?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Simply install the dependency yourself:

```
npm install jquery@1.9.1 --save
```

Although `--save` is optional I recommend to put it, so the next time you simply can type only `npm install` and both bootstrap and jquery will be installed. You can read about peer dependencies on npm [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies).

Comment: Isn't the whole point of npm to manage these dependencies lololol!?

Comment: I want npm to crash, burn and explode

Comment: in automated environment this is (virtually) not possible. the peerDep version may change and manually assigned one will be useless. In Docker I would need to write a script that reads npm i output and parses it for all missed peeDeps in order to determine what to install "manually".

Answer (score 3):

You should read the terminal whether **all important dependencies** have been installed. If it hasn't install those manually.

```
npm install <MISSING DEPENDANCY> --save
```

In your case

```
npm install jquery@1.9.1 --save
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the given answers:
If npm warns you about a missing dependency with a version **range** like `1.9.1 - 3` then you should definitely use that range to manually install the dependency – and not only its lower boundary. Use quotes for the range to work as a parameter in the install command. Both of the following examples will work:

```
npm install jquery@"1.9.1 - 3"
npm install "jquery@1.9.1 - 3"
```

Also the parameter `--save` can be omitted as of npm v5.0. This is the default now when you install.